# Make a View in SQLITE with the sum of value of each parent row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I got, for example two tables, One with a list of users... let say User Table

```
ID    Name
---------------
1     'Alejandro'
2     'Carlos'
3     'Pedro'
```

And another table with a list of transactions "Money" Table.

```
ID  ID_User   Money
---------------------
1   1         45.5
2   1         45.5
3   2         45.5
```

I want to build a view that allow me with some kind of dynamics the resume of each user... for example:

```
Name         Money
---------------------
'Alejandro'  91.0
'Carlos'     45.5
'Pedro'       0.0
```

I tried with Sub querys but i only got the sum of all money, and not a for each user.

Any help U_U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished either with a correlated subquery:

```
CREATE VIEW UserResume AS
SELECT Name,
       (SELECT TOTAL(Money)
        FROM Money
        WHERE ID_User = User.ID
       ) AS Money
FROM User
```

or with an outer join:

```
CREATE VIEW UserResume AS
SELECT Name,
       TOTAL(Money) AS Money
FROM User
LEFT JOIN Money ON User.ID = Money.ID_User
GROUP BY User.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with `join`s:

```
SELECT    name, SUM(money) AS money
FROM      user
LEFT JOIN money ON user.id = money.id_user
GROUP BY  name
```

Comment: This is not valid SQL, and will not return a record for Pedro.

Comment: Thanks; I forgot the GROUP BY myself. But your query still does not return anything for a user without a `Money` entry.